# How to create ico file with more than one image

Tags: imagemagick, icons

I can use ImageMagick to convert png to ico but (I think, not sure) it will create one image per ico file for the size I specify.

```
convert favicon.png -resize 32 favicon.ico
```

An ico file can contain 2 or 3 images for 16x16 32x32 and 64x64 pixels.

Is it possible to create such icon maybe with ImageMagick or other tool?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Newer versions have an easier command:

```
convert -background transparent image.png -define icon:auto-resize=16,32,48,64,256 favicon.ico
```

`-background transparent` is of course optional.

Answer (score 18):

Found it on [imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#favicon) site:

```
convert image.png  -bordercolor white -border 0 \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 64x64 \) \
      -delete 0 -alpha off -colors 256 favicon.ico
```